# Return the value of a callback function using a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

How can I return the value of `reverseGeocodeData` using a promise (using the resolve method in the promise)?

```
geocoder.reverseGeocode(33.7489, -84.3789,function (err, reverseGeocodeData){
    //something;
},
// Reverse Geocoding
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    resolve();
});
```

Comment: @Quentin this isn't a duplicate for that question, the issue is how to promisify an async function that takes a callback.

Comment: let geocode = (lat, long)=>geocoder.reverse(lat, long, (err, data)=> new Promise((resolve, reject)=>if(err) return reject(err); resolve(data)   ))

Comment: @Quentin a possible solution using promises is given, along a whole lot of other solutions to explain how to return a value _in general_. But IMO this isn't a general question about how to handle return values for async functions, but specifically how to wrap an async function with a promise.

Comment: @robertklep — The answer to the duplicate question still answers the specific question here.

Comment: @Quentin but the _question_ isn't the same.

Comment: @robertklep — It doesn't need to be perfectly identical. It's the same as part of the duplicate question and the answers to the duplicate answer this question.

Comment: @Quentin in that case, feel free to reclose it as a duplicate, I won't reopen it (although I don't agree :)

Comment: I can't. The system prevents me from doing that to avoid open/close wars. It needs someone who hasn't been involved in the moderation process yet to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve or reject the promise in the callback of the goecoder...

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    geocoder.reverseGeocode(33.7489, -84.3789, function (err, reverseGeocodeData) {
         if(err) return reject(err);
         resolve(reverseGeocodeData);
    });
});
```

This would be the basic implementation of a Promise. Depending on the promise library you're using there are of course other options. I prefer [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

Comment: Why the down vote? The answer isn't wrong. Is it unsatisfactory in some way?

Answer (score -1):

this is an example using bluebird.js (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var reverseGeocodePromise = Promise.promisify(geocoder.reverseGeocode);

reverseGeocodePromise(33.7489, -84.3789)
  .then(function(result) {
    // do something;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // handle error
  })
```

Comment: What wrong I did, why someone -1 to me